# React Navigation 5.0 Deep Linking not resolving

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using react native navigation 5.0 for deep linking

I'm using this to test. It gets into the application but it does not route to the right page.
I think my use case is quite simple / straightforward - i'm probably doing something stupid/wrong?

Thanks!

xcrun simctl openurl booted xx:/Chat/1234

```
 <NavigationContainer linking={linking} ref={navigationRef}>
     <Stack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeContainer} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatContainer} />
    ...
 </NavigationContainer>


const linking = {
    prefixes: ['https://xx.com', 'xx://'],
    config: {
      Chat: {
          path: 'Chat/:groupId',
          params:{
            groupId: null,
          }
      }
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i have to use initial state. then it worked.

```
  const { getInitialState } = useLinking(ref, {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config
  });

<NavigationContainer initialState={initialState} ref={ref}>
```